# D3: Add border around clip-path

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I'm aiming to add a border around the circular avatars I create in my D3 visualization. I create these circular avatars by using `clip-path`. When I add a border to my node it is a square border around the whole node, rather than circular like I'm aiming for (and I understand why, because this node is rectangular). Here is what that currently looks like:

[image]

I'm struggling in getting this border to instead appear around the circular, clipped, image.

Here is the code where I currently set the (rectangular) border:

```
var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('svg:g')
  .attr('class', 'node')
  .attr('cursor', 'pointer')
  .attr('style', function(d) {
    var color;
    if (d.strength > 2) {
      color = 'blue';
    } else {
      color = 'red';
    }
    return 'outline: thick solid ' + color + ';';
  })
  .attr('transform', function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  })
  .call(force.drag);
```

...and this is how I declare my `clip-path`:

```
var clipPath = defs.append('clipPath')
  .attr('id', 'clip-circle')
  .append('circle')
  .attr('r', 25);
```

My full example can be found here:
http://blockbuilder.org/MattDionis/5f966a5230079d9eb9f4

How would I go about setting this as a circular border around the image rather than rectangular around the entire node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add a circle of slightly larger radius (then your clip-path) into your node:

```
   nodeEnter.append('circle')
      .attr('r',30)
      .style('fill', function(d) {
        return d.strength > 2 ? 'blue' : 'red'
      });

    var images = nodeEnter.append('svg:image')
      .attr('xlink:href',  function(d) {
        return d.avatarUrl;
      })
      .attr('x', function(d) {
        return -25;
      })
      .attr('y', function(d) {
        return -25;
      })
      .attr('height', 50)
      .attr('width', 50)
      .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip-circle)');
```

Updated [code](http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/cbb9c0431ea4f25e263b).